# Windows Connection to Local Computers is Slow by Name but Fast by IP Address

Tags: windows-10, networking, powershell, lan, hosts

On Windows 10, I have several computers hooked up together with ethernet cables and each machine has its own static local IP address, like this:

[image]

Given this setup, if I try to connect computers to each other with their computer name, it is far slower than if I do it using IP addresses directly. For example

```
function Test-Port
{ # https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/hwfp1q/comment/fyzgpmw
  param ( [string]$Computer = '.', [int]$Port = 3389, [int]$Millisecond = 300 )
  $Test = New-Object -TypeName Net.Sockets.TcpClient
  ( $Test.BeginConnect( $Computer, $Port, $Null, $Null ) ).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne( $Millisecond )
  $Test.Close()
}

$compArray = "BOB-COMPUTER","JOE-COMPUTER","JOHN-COMPUTER"
$timearr = 0,25,50,100,200,400,800,1600,3200
foreach($computername in $compArray)
{
  write-host $computername
  foreach($ii in $timearr)
  {
    $isonline = Test-Port -Computer "$computername" -Millisecond $ii
    write-host "    " $ii $isonline
  }
}
```

gives

```
BOB-COMPUTER
     0 False
     25 False
     50 False
     100 False
     200 False
     400 False
     800 False
     1600 True
     3200 True
JOE-COMPUTER
     0 False
     25 False
     50 False
     100 False
     200 False
     400 False
     800 False
     1600 True
     3200 True
JOHN-COMPUTER
     0 False
     25 False
     50 False
     100 False
     200 False
     400 False
     800 False
     1600 True
     3200 True
```

but if I do it with IP addresses instead

`$compArray = "192.168.0.201","192.168.0.202","192.168.0.209"`

```
BOB-COMPUTER
     0 True
     25 True
     50 True
     100 True
     200 True
     400 True
     800 True
     1600 True
     3200 True
JOE-COMPUTER
     0 False
     25 True
     50 True
     100 True
     200 True
     400 True
     800 True
     1600 True
     3200 True
JOHN-COMPUTER
     0 False
     25 True
     50 True
     100 True
     200 True
     400 True
     800 True
     1600 True
     3200 True
```

it's far faster. I notice it's a lot slower when simply attempting to connect over file explorer or remote desktop connections as well. How can I speed it up so using the computer name is as fast (or nearly as fast) as using the IP address throughout all of Windows?

Comment: I assume you modified the hosts file?

Comment: Try NET USE Z:  \\computer\folder and authenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the host file?

Add the following lines to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
192.168.0.201 BOB-COMPUTER
192.168.0.202 JOE-COMPUTER
192.168.0.209 JOHN-COMPUTER
```

Maybe this won't solve the problem fundamentally, but at least this will make it be the same whether to use names or addresses.

Comment: This did work, but I suspect this file isn't intended to be edited directly given it requires administrator permission to access. Is this really the correct approach to take? Just modifying it directly with a text editor? There's no GUI way to do it? Do I have to worry about this getting overwritten by an OS process at some point later down the line?

Comment: @jippyjoe4 Relax, :D

1. Is it correct to modify it with a text editor?

    Yes. This is just a simple text file used by Windows. It's structure is so simple that there is no need to make a GUI for it. Any text editor can do the job.

2. Will any process modify this file?

    As far as I know, very few applications ever try to modify this file. Also, I think there may be no OS processes either. Because this file is an intended method for Windows to customize host resolution. In fact, you can consider this as a local DNS server. Windows prepares it just for users to configure.

Comment: @jippyjoe4 It will effect all applications in your computer. For example, if there is a HTTP server at BOB-COMPUTER's 8080 port, then both `http://192.168.0.201:8080` and `http://BOB-COMPUTER:8080` will lead you to the web site in your browser (Edge/Chrome/Firefox...).